# Conormal distributions and the wave front set

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, differential-operators, schwartz-distributions, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $X$ be a smooth closed manifold and $Y$ a regular submanifold. For all conormal distributions at $Y$ on $X$, their wave front set is contained in the conormal bundle of $Y$. Is the reciprocal true? In another way, is this a characteristic property of conormal distributions?

Comment: Isn’t this the definition of a conormal distribution?

Comment: The definition is as follows. Let $\mathcal V(X,Y)$ be the Lie algebra of vector fields on $X$ tangent to $Y$, let $\operatorname{Diff}(X,Y)$ be the algebra of differential operators generated by $C^\infty(X)$ and $\mathcal V(X,Y)$, and let $H^s(X)$ be the Sobolev space of order $s$. Then let $I^{[s]}(X,Y)$ be the space of distributions $u$ on $X$ such that $\operatorname{Diff}(X,Y)u\subset H^s(X)$. The space of conormal distributions is $I(X,Y)=\bigcup_sI^{[s]}(X,Y)$. There's another description of $I(X,Y)$ using symbols, which is more involved.

Comment: Minor point: you did assume $X$ to be closed ( = compact without boundary), but otherwise it should be pointed that the notion of conormal distributions is local, meaning that you should use $H^s_{loc}$ instead of $H^s$, also because you need to choose a volume element on $X$ to define $H^s(X)$ whereas $H^s_{loc}(X)$ is independent of that choice. Finally, even with such a choice, depending on the growth of the coefficients of $P\in\text{Diff}(X,Y)$ alone it may happen that $u\in H^s(X)$ but $Pu\not\in H^s(X)$ regardless of whether there is loss of regularity or not.

Comment: @Pedro Lauridsen Ribeiro. Right, I assumed $X$ is closed for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the one-dimensional situation: $X = \mathbb{R}, Y = \{0\}$ (the notion of conormal distribution is local, so the fact that $X$ is not closed doesn't really matter). Then any distribution that is smooth outside of $Y$ has its wave front set in the conormal bundle. On the other hand, a distribution $f$ being conormal is a very particular asymptotic condition at $0$: specifically, $x^n f \in \operatorname{H}^{s+n}_{\operatorname{loc}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This is not guaranteed in general: e.g., for a function like $f(x) = \sin e^{-1/x^2}$ the degree of smoothness of $x^n f$ won't improve with $n$.